# Why do I always need "ruby" in front of "script/runner"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, cron, whenever

When I do just `script/runner` it gives me `-bash: script/runner: Permission denied`

When I do `sudo script/runner` it gives me `sudo: script/runner: command not found`

It only works when I do `ruby script/runner`. Why? Everywhere else I see people just run `script/runner` without the `ruby` in front of it... Is there a "fix" for this? It's causing my javan-whenever generated crontab to fail on `Permission denied` because it just runs `script/runner` without `ruby`...

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like the "execute" permission bit is not set on your `script/runner` file.  If that bit is not set, the unix shells will not try to execute it.

`chmod +x script/runner` can be used to set it.  `man chmod` for more details on the chmod command.

Answer (score 3):

just do this

> chmod +x script/runner

and it would run. It basically makes it a executable.

use

> man chmod

to get more details

Comment: oh that's great!! :D now a tack-on question... i'm using capistrano to deploy... do i need to add `chmod +x script/runner` as part of my deploy process or can i, for example, do that on the repository, or something? thanks!

Comment: you create custom tasks in cucumber to do that.